# Using longtable with multicolumn heading

Tags: longtable, multicolumn

I am formatting a table for my dissertation. The graduate school requires that the margins be 1.25 inches on each side and 1 inch from top/bottom of the text. So that table below is too large to fit on one page. I would like to use the longtable feature but am unsure how to do this as (1) I need to repeat the first row on each page and (2) I have a multicolumn table. I would like the table to break after Recycle vs. Store results (i.e. sub-column VI). The lengthy number of packages are requirements for the graduate school template. Please let me know if you have any suggestions!

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,threeparttable,caption}
% Additional packages here
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{natbib,epstopdf}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet5'
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[h]\centering
   \caption{MNL Model with Grouped Disposal as DV}
   \footnotesize{
\begin{tabular}{lccccccccccc}
\cmidrule{2-12}          & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Recycle vs. Trash }} &       & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Recycle vs. Store }} &       & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Store vs Trash }} \\
\cmidrule{2-12}          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{I} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{II} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{III} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{IV} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{V} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{VI} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{VII} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{VIII} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{IX} \\
          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Std. Error} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Odds ratio} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Std. Error} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Odds ratio} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Coef.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Std. Error} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Odds ratio} \\
\cmidrule{2-12}    1. EPR: Yes & $0.44^{*}$  & 0.21  & 1.55  &       & 0.06  & 0.18  & 1.06  &       & 0.38  & 0.24  & 1.46 \\
    1. LEGALAWARENESS: Yes & 0.07  & 0.22  & 1.07  &       & -$0.34^{*}$ & 0.16  & 0.71  &       & 0.41  & 0.25  & 1.50 \\
    1. LOCTAWARENESS: Maybe & $1.37^{***}$  & 0.23  & 3.92  &       & 1.17  & 0.19  & 3.92  &       & 0.20  & 0.28  & 1.22 \\
    2. LOCTAWARENESS: Yes & $1.67^{***}$  & 0.26  & 5.30  &       & $1.48^{***}$  & 0.20  & 4.41  &       & 0.18  & 0.30  & 1.20 \\
    2. IMPORTANCE: Not very & -0.08 & 0.66  & 0.95  &       & -0.65 & 0.95  & 0.52  &       & 0.56  & 0.88  & 1.76 \\
    3. IMPORTANCE: Neutral & $1.03^{\hat{}}$  & 0.58  & 2.80  &       & 0.25  & 0.87  & 1.28  &       & 0.78  & 0.82  & 2.18 \\
    4. IMPORTANCE: Somewhat Important & $1.95^{**}$  & 0.57  & 7.06  &       & -0.32 & 0.84  & 0.73  &       & $2.28^{**}$  & 0.80  & 9.74 \\
    5. IMPORTANCE: Very Important & $2.34^{***}$  & 0.57  & 10.41 &       & 0.02  & 0.85  & 10.41 &       & $2.32^{**}$  & 0.81  & 10.17 \\
    1. INFOSOURCE: General & 0.41  & 0.34  & 1.51  &       & $1.19^{***}$  & 0.31  & 3.30  &       & -$0.78^{*}$ & 0.40  & 0.46 \\
    2. INFOSOURCE: Government & $0.76^{*}$  & 0.36  & 2.14  &       & $1.08^{***}$  & 0.30  & 2.94  &       & -0.32 & 0.40  & 0.73 \\
    3. INFOSOURCE: Retailer Manufacturer & 0.55  & 0.39  & 1.74  &       & $0.77^{**}$  & 0.34  & 2.66  &       & -0.42 & 0.46  & 0.65 \\
    4. INFOSOURCE: Non Profit & $0.77^{*}$  & 0.38  & 2.16  &       & $1.09^{***}$  & 0.32  & 2.98  &       & -0.32 & 0.44  & 0.73 \\
    1. PREVENT: Too Expensive & -1.19 & 0.77  & 0.31  &       & -0.60 & 0.47  & 0.55  &       & -0.59 & 0.89  & 0.55 \\
    2. PREVENT: Inconvenient Location & -$1.73^{*}$ & 0.74  & 0.18  &       & -$1.06^{*}$ & 0.45  & 0.35  &       & -0.67 & 0.86  & 0.51 \\
    3. PREVENT: Unable to Transport & -1.13 & 0.75  & 0.32  &       & -0.22 & 0.47  & 0.81  &       & -0.91 & 0.88  & 0.40 \\
    4. PREVENT: Unaware of Location & -$1.57^{*}$ & 0.73  & 0.21  &       & -$0.87^{*}$ & 0.46  & 0.42  &       & -0.70 & 0.86  & 0.50 \\
    1. RURAL: Yes & -0.23 & 0.19  & 0.78  &       & -$0.37^{**}$ & 0.15  & 0.69  &       & 0.14  & 0.22  & 1.16 \\
    2. AGE: 36-45 & 0.35  & 0.29  & 1.43  &       & 0.05  & 0.20  & 2.95  &       & 0.31  & 0.32  & 0.58 \\
    3. AGE: 46-55 & 0.00  & 0.25  & 0.98  &       & $0.94^{***}$  & 0.23  & 2.55  &       & -$0.94^{**}$ & 0.31  & 0.39 \\
    4. AGE: 56-65 & 0.44  & 0.28  & 1.49  &       & $1.09^{***}$  & 0.24  & 2.95  &       & -$0.65^{*}$ & 0.33  & 0.52 \\
    5. AGE: 66+ & $0.60^{\hat{}}$  & 0.34  & 1.82  &       & $1.14^{***}$  & 0.29  & 3.13  &       & -0.54 & 0.41  & 0.58 \\
    2. DISTANCE: 1-5 miles & $0.61^{**}$  & 0.23  & 1.83  &       & 0.45  & 0.28  & 1.57  &       & -$0.47^{**}$ & 0.41  & 0.62 \\
    3. DISTANCE: 6-10 miles & 0.38  & 0.25  & 1.46  &       & 0.33  & 0.27  & 1.39  &       & 0.25  & 0.40  & 1.29 \\
    4. DISTANCE: 11-20 miles & $0.02^{\hat{}}$  & 0.34  & 1.02  &       & 0.54  & 0.29  & 1.42  &       & -0.19 & 0.42  & 0.83 \\
    \bottomrule
     \midrule
\textit{***p $<$ .001, ** p $<$.01, *p$<$.05, $^\wedge$ p$<$.1} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &        \\
\end{tabular}}
  \label{tab:results}%
\end{table}%
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a **minimal** working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem.  A MWE load only necessary packages.

Comment: You can break a longtable after a *row*, not after a *column*.

Answer (score 3):

- First step: clean-up your MWE:

[image]

MWE (not consider complete provided table, for it is to much work and you can finish it on the same way as it is shown for eight first rows:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}

% Additional packages here
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
   \caption{MNL Model with Grouped Disposal as DV}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}
                {@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                l 
           *{3}{S[table-format=-1.2, 
                  table-space-text-post={***}] 
                S[table-format=1.2] 
                S[table-format=2.2]}
                }
\cmidrule{2-10}          
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{Recycle vs. Trash }} 
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{Recycle vs. Store }} 
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{Store vs Trash }} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}          
\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-10}
    & {I}       & {II} & {III} & {IV} & {V} & {VI} & {VII} & {VIII} & {IX} \\
    & {Coef.}   
    & {\makecell[b]{Std.\\ Error}} 
    & {\makecell[b]{Odds\\ ratio}} 
    & {Coef.} 
    & {\makecell[b]{Std.\\ Error}}
    & {\makecell[b]{Odds\\ ratio}}
    & {Coef.}   
    & {\makecell[b]{Std.\\ Error}} 
    & {\makecell[b]{Odds\\ ratio}} \\
\midrule   
1. EPR: Yes     
    & 0.44* & 0.21  & 1.55  & 0.06  & 0.18  & 1.06  & 0.38  & 0.24  & 1.46  \\
1. LEGALAWARENESS: Yes 
    & 0.07  & 0.22  & 1.07  & -0.34 & 0.16  & 0.71  & 0.41  & 0.25  & 1.50 \\
1. LOCTAWARENESS: Maybe 
    &  1.37***  & 0.23 & 3.92 & 1.17 & 0.19 & 3.92  & 0.20  & 0.28  & 1.22 \\
2. LOCTAWARENESS: Yes 
    & 1.67***   & 0.26 & 5.30 & 1.48*** & 0.20  & 4.41  & 0.18  & 0.30  & 1.20 \\
2. IMPORTANCE: Not very 
    & -0.08 & 0.66  & 0.95 & -0.65 & 0.95  & 0.52  & 0.56  & 0.88  & 1.76 \\
3. IMPORTANCE: Neutral 
    & 1.03  & 0.58  & 2.80 & 0.25  & 0.87  & 1.28  & 0.78  & 0.82  & 2.18 \\
4. IMPORTANCE: Somewhat Important 
    & 1.95**    & 0.57  & 7.06  & -0.32 & 0.84  & 0.73  & 2.28**   & 0.80  & 9.74 \\
5. IMPORTANCE: Very Important 
    & 2.34  & 0.57  & 10.41 & 0.02  & 0.85  & 10.41 & 2.32{**}  & 0.81  & 10.17 \\
     \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{10}{l}{
\textit{***p $<$ .001, ** p $<$.01, *p$<$.05, $^\wedge$ p$<$.1}
                    }
\end{tabular*}
  \label{tab:results}%
\end{table}%
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

- second step: transform your table to long table. For `longtable` is not possible to prescribe table width, however experiences from standard table show, that it will fit to available text width with equal settings for `\tabcolsep`.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, longtable}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
% Additional packages here
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet5'
\begin{landscape}

    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{longtable}{
                l 
           *{3}{S[table-format=-1.2, 
                  table-space-text-post={***}] 
                S[table-format=1.2] 
                S[table-format=2.2]}
                }
    \caption{MNL Model with Grouped Disposal as DV} 
    \label{tab:results}                             \\%
\cmidrule{2-10}          
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{Recycle vs. Trash }} 
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{Recycle vs. Store }} 
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{Store vs Trash }}   \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}          
\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-10}
    & {I}       & {II} & {III} & {IV} & {V} & {VI} & {VII} & {VIII} & {IX} \\
    & {Coef.}   
    & {\makecell[b]{Std.\\ Error}} 
    & {\makecell[b]{Odds\\ ratio}} 
    & {Coef.} 
    & {\makecell[b]{Std.\\ Error}}
    & {\makecell[b]{Odds\\ ratio}}
    & {Coef.}   
    & {\makecell[b]{Std.\\ Error}} 
    & {\makecell[b]{Odds\\ ratio}} \\
\midrule 
    \endfirsthead
%%%%
    \caption{MNL Model with Grouped Disposal as DV (Cont.)} \\
\cmidrule{2-10}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{Recycle vs. Trash }}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{Recycle vs. Store }}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{Store vs Trash }} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-10}
    & {I}       & {II} & {III} & {IV} & {V} & {VI} & {VII} & {VIII} & {IX} \\
    & {Coef.}
    & {\makecell[b]{Std.\\ Error}}
    & {\makecell[b]{Odds\\ ratio}}
    & {Coef.}
    & {\makecell[b]{Std.\\ Error}}
    & {\makecell[b]{Odds\\ ratio}}
    & {Coef.}
    & {\makecell[b]{Std.\\ Error}}
    & {\makecell[b]{Odds\\ ratio}} \\
\midrule
    \endhead
%%%%  
%\midrule
\multicolumn{10}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape
                    Continue on the next page}
    \endfoot
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{10}{l}{
\textit{***p $<$ .001, ** p $<$.01, *p$<$.05, $^\wedge$ p$<$.1}
                    }
    \endlastfoot
%%%% table content
1. EPR: Yes     
    & 0.44* & 0.21  & 1.55  & 0.06  & 0.18  & 1.06  & 0.38  & 0.24  & 1.46  \\
1. LEGALAWARENESS: Yes 
    & 0.07  & 0.22  & 1.07  & -0.34 & 0.16  & 0.71  & 0.41  & 0.25  & 1.50 \\
1. LOCTAWARENESS: Maybe 
    &  1.37***  & 0.23 & 3.92 & 1.17 & 0.19 & 3.92  & 0.20  & 0.28  & 1.22 \\
2. LOCTAWARENESS: Yes 
    & 1.67***   & 0.26 & 5.30 & 1.48*** & 0.20  & 4.41  & 0.18  & 0.30  & 1.20 \\
2. IMPORTANCE: Not very 
    & -0.08 & 0.66  & 0.95 & -0.65 & 0.95  & 0.52  & 0.56  & 0.88  & 1.76 \\
3. IMPORTANCE: Neutral 
    & 1.03  & 0.58  & 2.80 & 0.25  & 0.87  & 1.28  & 0.78  & 0.82  & 2.18 \\
4. IMPORTANCE: Somewhat Important 
    & 1.95**    & 0.57  & 7.06  & -0.32 & 0.84  & 0.73  & 2.28**   & 0.80  & 9.74 \\
5. IMPORTANCE: Very Important 
    & 2.34  & 0.57  & 10.41 & 0.02  & 0.85  & 10.41 & 2.32{**}  & 0.81  & 10.17 \\
\end{longtable}%
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Layout of table is very similar as before:

[image]

- page layout: I didn't bother with it, It can be simply determined by package `geometry`. For example:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.25in, vmargin=1in]{geometry}
```

- Third step: preamble. It is sufficient to load each package only once :). Please remove all duplicate and group them for its purpose (for tables, for units, for caption, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in `landscape` mode  with `ltablex`, which gives `tabularx` the possibility to break across pages (same syntax as with `longtable`), and `threeparttablex`, which extends `threeparttable` (for table notes) to tables breaking across pages, with a slightly different syntax.

Comment aside: it's better to load `[utf8]` input encoding, as all modern editors understand `utf8` and use it by default (except perhaps TeXshop):

```
    \documentclass[english]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{ltablex, caption, makecell, hhline, booktabs, threeparttablex}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \newcommand*\tss[1]{\,\textsuperscript{#1}}

    \keepXColumns

    \begin{document}

    \begin{landscape}
        \footnotesize\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
        \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
        \sisetup{table-number-alignment=center, range-phrase=--}
        \begin{ThreePartTable}
          \begin{TableNotes}[para]
            \item[***]$ p < .001 $,
            \item[**] $ p <.01 $,
            \item[*] $ p<.05 $,
            \item[$ ^ ∧ $] $ p<.1 $.
          \end{TableNotes}
          \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X@{}*{3}{S[table-format=-1.2, table-space-text-post=\tss{***}] S[table-format=1.2] S[table-format=2.2]}@{}}
           \caption{MNL Model with Grouped Disposal as DV} \\
            \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-10} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Recycle vs. Trash }} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Recycle vs. Store }} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Store vs Trash }} \\
            \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}\cmidrule(l){8-10} %
                                                            & { \makecell{I \\Coef.}} & {\makecell{II\\Std. Error}} & {\makecell{III\\Odds ratio}} & {\makecell{IV\\Coef.}} & {\makecell{V\\Std. Error}} & {\makecell{VI\\Odds ratio}} & {\makecell{VII\\Coef.}} & {\makecell{VIII\\Std. Error}} & {\makecell{IX\\Odds ratio}} \\%
            \cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](l){2-10} \\
            \endfirsthead
            \multicolumn{10}{c}{Table \thetable}{}(continued)\\
            \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-10} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Recycle vs. Trash }} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Recycle vs. Store }} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Store vs Trash }} \\
            \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}\cmidrule(l){8-10} %
                                                            & { \makecell{I \\Coef.}} & {\makecell{II\\Std. Error}} & {\makecell{III\\Odds ratio}} & {\makecell{IV\\Coef.}} & {\makecell{V\\Std. Error}} & {\makecell{VI\\Odds ratio}} & {\makecell{VII\\Coef.}} & {\makecell{VIII\\Std. Error}} & {\makecell{IX\\Odds ratio}} \\%
            \cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](l){2-10} \\
            \endhead
\\\multicolumn{10}{r}{To be continued}
\endfoot
\\
            \bottomrule
            \midrule
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
            1. EPR: Yes & 0.44$ \tnote{*} $ & 0.21 & 1.55 & 0.06 & 0.18 & 1.06 & 0.38 & 0.24 & 1.46 \\
            1. LEGALAWARENESS: Yes & 0.07 & 0.22 & 1.07 & -0.34\tnote{*} & 0.16 & 0.71 & 0.41 & 0.25 & 1.50 \\
            1. LOCTAWARENESS: Maybe & 1.37\tnote{***} & 0.23 & 3.92 & 1.17 & 0.19 & 3.92 & 0.20 & 0.28 & 1.22 \\
            2. LOCTAWARENESS: Yes & 1.67\tnote{***} & 0.26 & 5.30 & 1.48\tnote{***} & 0.20 & 4.41 & 0.18 & 0.30 & 1.20 \\
            2. IMPORTANCE: Not very & -0.08 & 0.66 & 0.95 & -0.65 & 0.95 & 0.52 & 0.56 & 0.88 & 1.76 \\
            3. IMPORTANCE: Neutral & 1.03\tnote{$ ∧ $} & 0.58 & 2.80 & 0.25 & 0.87 & 1.28 & 0.78 & 0.82 & 2.18 \\
            4. IMPORTANCE: Somewhat Important & 1.95\tnote{**} & 0.57 & 7.06 & -0.32 & 0.84 & 0.73 & 2.28\tnote{**} & 0.80 & 9.74 \\
            5. IMPORTANCE: Very Important & 2.34\tnote{***} & 0.57 & 10.41 & 0.02 & 0.85 & 10.41 & 2.32\tnote{**} & 0.81 & 10.17 \\
            1. INFOSOURCE: General & 0.41 & 0.34 & 1.51 & 1.19\tnote{***} & 0.31 & 3.30 & -0.78\tnote{*} & 0.40 & 0.46 \\
            2. INFOSOURCE: Government & 0.76\tnote{*} & 0.36 & 2.14 & 1.08\tnote{***} & 0.30 & 2.94 & -0.32 & 0.40 & 0.73 \\
            3. INFOSOURCE: Retailer Manufacturer & 0.55 & 0.39 & 1.74 & 0.77\tnote{**} & 0.34 & 2.66 & -0.42 & 0.46 & 0.65 \\
            4. INFOSOURCE: Non Profit & 0.77\tnote{*} & 0.38 & 2.16 & 1.09\tnote{***} & 0.32 & 2.98 & -0.32 & 0.44 & 0.73 \\
            1. PREVENT: Too Expensive & -1.19 & 0.77 & 0.31 & -0.60 & 0.47 & 0.55 & -0.59 & 0.89 & 0.55 \\
            2. PREVENT: Inconvenient Location & -1.73\tnote{*} & 0.74 & 0.18 & -1.06\tnote{*} & 0.45 & 0.35 & -0.67 & 0.86 & 0.51 \\
            3. PREVENT: Unable to Transport & -1.13 & 0.75 & 0.32 & -0.22 & 0.47 & 0.81 & -0.91 & 0.88 & 0.40 \\
            4. PREVENT: Unaware of Location & -1.57\tnote{*} & 0.73 & 0.21 & -0.87\tnote{*} & 0.46 & 0.42 & -0.70 & 0.86 & 0.50 \\
            1. RURAL: Yes & -0.23 & 0.19 & 0.78 & -0.37\tnote{**} & 0.15 & 0.69 & 0.14 & 0.22 & 1.16 \\
            2. AGE: \numrange{36}{45} & 0.35 & 0.29 & 1.43 & 0.05 & 0.20 & 2.95 & 0.31 & 0.32 & 0.58 \\
            3. AGE: \numrange{46}{55} & 0.00 & 0.25 & 0.98 & 0.94\tnote{***} & 0.23 & 2.55 & -0.94\tnote{**} & 0.31 & 0.39 \\
            4. AGE: \numrange{56}{65} & 0.44 & 0.28 & 1.49 & 1.09\tnote{***} & 0.24 & 2.95 & -0.65\tnote{*} & 0.33 & 0.52 \\
            5. AGE: 66\,+ & 0.60\tnote{$ ∧ $} & 0.34 & 1.82 & 1.14\tnote{***} & 0.29 & 3.13 & -0.54 & 0.41 & 0.58 \\
            2. DISTANCE: \numrange{1}{5} miles & 0.61\tnote{**} & 0.23 & 1.83 & 0.45 & 0.28 & 1.57 & -0.47\tnote{**} & 0.41 & 0.62 \\
            3. DISTANCE: \numrange{6}{10} miles & 0.38 & 0.25 & 1.46 & 0.33 & 0.27 & 1.39 & 0.25 & 0.40 & 1.29 \\
            4. DISTANCE: \numrange{11}{20} miles & 0.02\tnote{$ ∧ $} & 0.34 & 1.02 & 0.54 & 0.29 & 1.42 & -0.19 & 0.42 & 0.83
          \end{tabularx}%}%}
          \label{tab:results}%
        \end{ThreePartTable}
    \end{landscape}

    \end{document}
```

[image]